# How to show in a custom QGIS form the feature and/or geometry info?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, features, qgis-2, getfeatureinfo

I need to show point coordinates on the from dialog used to edit the attributes of a point..
I see that in the formOpen the dialog receives a layerId and a featureId, but no iface object, so how can get a provider to use the selectatId() and reach feature informations?

```
def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):
...omissis...
```

(see **[here](http://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/)** for a more detailed explanation of custom qgis forms)

Comment: What version of QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

never mind.
I was fooled by the function declaration used in the example.
Actually, it should be:

```
def formOpen(dialog,layer,feature):
    ...omissis...
    geometry = feature.geometry()
    wktString = geometry.exportToWkt()
```

That is: the function is receiving the ACTUAL object, not it's id.
So I can access the geometry by direct function call.

Comment: My blog post if pre 2.0 which used to only get pasted the feature id.  Now it gets passed the whole object.