# Finding the layer in a QGIS Custom dialog

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a custom form that calculates some area values, I'd like to automatically fill the base field using the geometry of the feature if the user hasn't set some value specifically. So I have the following code:

```
def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):
    global sqMField
    sqMField = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"property_area_m2")
    global sqFtField
    sqFtField = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"property_area_ft2")
    global haField
    haField = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"area_area_ha")
    global acreField
    acreField = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"property_area_acres")
    sqMField.textChanged.connect( sqMChanged )
    #if sqMField.text().strip() is None:
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()[layerid]
    feature = layer.getFeature(featureid)
    if feature.hasGeometry():
        area = feature.geometry().area()
        sqMField.setText(str(area))
```

This is called when I use the identify tool on a layer, having set this function as the `Python init function` on the fields tab of the layer properties. Thus I'm assuming the QGIS fills the parameters in for me?

But I get a `KeyError` error and on further checking it seems like I get a different `layerid` parameter each time the dialog opens, e.g:

```
An error occurred during execution of following code:
formOpen( _qgis_featureform_50_31, _qgis_layer_register20150529183519760_31, _qgis_feature_20170214103800202)

An error occurred during execution of following code:
formOpen( _qgis_featureform_51_32, _qgis_layer_register20150529183519760_32, _qgis_feature_20170214103829234)
```

So I could probably fix it by stripping some stuff off the `layerid` but that seems wrong. Can anyone show me what I'm missing?

Comment: Instead of matching the layer by id (since it seems to change dynamically), match it by name? E.g. `layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("name")[0]`

Comment: but I don't know the name of the layer

Comment: @iant Could you please post how did you define the `layerid` and `featureid` variables? I mean, a sample of line where you define them.

Comment: as a python init function on identify clicks (see updated q)

Comment: Thanks, @iant. Maybe I have completely misunderstood your issue. Are you trying to: 1) click a point in the map for triggering the function 2) call every layer (and feature) which intersects the clicked coordinates from the Identify tool, and then 3) check if a specified field contains a value for the area?

Comment: @mgri - no I'm using a custom form that opens when I use the identify tool on my layer. You can set an init function that is run before the form is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the layer- and the feature-handler like this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

nameField = None
myDialog = None
myLayer = None
sqMField = None

def formOpen(dialog,layer,featureid):
    global myDialog
    global sqMField
    myDialog = dialog
    sqMField = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"property_area_m2")
    myLayer = layer
    print layer
    feature = featureid
    print feature
    if feature.geometry():
        area = feature.geometry().area()
        print area
        sqMField.setText(str(area))
```

Comment: fantastic, so in fact I get passed the layer and feature - bonus points if you can point to the manual entry that would have told me that?

Comment: I think there is no manual entry for this topic. Many people refer to Nathan Woodrows blogpost: https://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/. I found a comment from Nathan Woodrow about this blogpost which is important: "My blog post is pre 2.0 which used to only get pasted the feature id. Now it gets passed the whole object." ( https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79755/how-to-show-in-a-custom-qgis-form-the-feature-and-or-geometry-info )